# Popup window at YII2 gridview problems

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I try to make a web application (CRUD application) for my company to manage their storage. 
I use Yii2 framework to make it easy and use a lot of plugin from kartik-v
But I have a problem with popup window. actually, I have to show all storage item in a gridview and I want to make a popup windows for its feature. I have already done it for "create" but I cant do the same way with show, edit, and update feature because it(the button link) is included in the table ->actioncolumn.
I try to find some answer and it lead me to a popup-dialogue but it doesn't work as it should be. I try it to view button. I shows the popup for a while then it directed to view page. I really want no make it just a popup. someone can help me please?

here is my code for action grid column:

```
       [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header' => 'Actions',
            'vAlign' => 'middle',
            'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {popupview}',
            'buttons' => [
                'popupview' => function ($url, $model) {
                    $url = Url::to(['companies/view' , 'id' => $model->company_id]);
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" title"></span>',$url, ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'value' => Url::to(['companies/view' , 'id' => $model->company_id]), 'id' => 'viewButton']);
                },
            ],
        ],
```

and here is my modals init:

```
<?php
    Modal::begin([
        'header' => '<h4>Companies</h4>',
        'id' => 'view',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
    ]);

    echo "<div id='viewContent'></div>";

    Modal::end();
?>
```

and here is my javascript for popup:

```
$(function(){
$('#viewButton').click(function(){
    $('#view').modal('show')
        .find('#viewContent')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
});});
```

can someone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button link (you use a link) they redirect on the view page, to prevent this you shoul use

```
$('#viewButton').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //rest of the code
});
```

But it's not enough, to load the content of the view in the modal, you have to call it via ajax like this

```
$('#viewButton').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       url : '',
       data: '',
       success: function (response) {
          $('#viewContent').html(response);
    });

});
```

And in you controller you must use the method RenderAjax to render the view

Comment: This is an example, you have to adjust this code for your needs

Comment: thank you for the response. Actually, it is working for the view page just using preventdefault. I will let you know the update.